# The derivative of the inclusion map as a tangent space isomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to solve an exercise that is concerned with tangent space isomorphisms.

[image]

I have an issue with the proof that $d_p i$ is an isomorphism.
M is a smooth manifold, so it admits a smooth structure $(V_j, \psi_j)_{j \in J}$. Because $U$ is an open subset of $M$ it is a smooth manifold with a smooth structure $(U_j,\varphi_j)_{j \in J}$ where $U_j:=U \cap V_j$ and $\varphi_j:=\psi_j |_{U_j}$. For $p \in U$ we find a chart $(O,\varphi)$ from the smooth structure on $U$ such that $p \in U$. Since $O$ and $\varphi(O)$ are both open we can see them as smooth manifolds. Then $\varphi: O \to \varphi(O)$ is a diffeomorphism. Then the differential

$$
d_p \varphi: T_p O \to T_{\varphi(p)} \varphi(O)
$$

is an isomorphism with inverse $d_{\varphi(p)} \varphi^{-1}$. Define $f:=\varphi \circ i \circ \varphi^{-1}$. Then $f=id_O$ is a diffeomorphism and the differential

$$
d_{\varphi(p)} f: T_{\varphi(p)} \varphi(O) \to T_{\varphi(p)} \varphi(O) 
$$

is an isomorphism. By the chain rule we have

$$
d_{\varphi(p)} f=d_{i(p)} \varphi 
\circ d_p i 
\circ d_{\varphi(p)} \varphi^{-1}. 
$$

Then

$$
d_p i=(d_{i(p)} \varphi)^{-1} 
\circ d_{\varphi(p)} f
\circ (d_p \varphi^{-1})^{-1}                                      \\
=d_{\varphi(p)} \varphi^{-1} 
\circ d_{\varphi(p)} f
\circ d_p \varphi
$$

So $d_p i$ is a composition of isomorphisms and therefore an isomorphism itself. But this only considers $d_p i$ as a map from $T_p O$ to $T_p O$. I am a bit confused about how to proceed to show that the claim also holds when $d_p i$ is taken as a map from $T_p U$ to $T_p M$.

Comment: Dimension count:  $U$ is open so it is a manifold of the same dimension as $M$.

Comment: According to your understanding, for fixed $p\in U\subset M$, what is the difference between $T_pU$ and $T_pM$?